# Error handling errors while using api.retweet() Tweepy 3.5/ Python3

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

My application is to retweet a hashtag using Tweepy. Retweeting the hashtag works, I am having trouble getting errors 2 and 3 to work.
Errors
1. Your own id (done)
2. If tweet has already been RTd 
3. If tweet to RT comes from protected source

Accessing api.retweet(doTweet) within the StdOutListener does not allow it to fall through to on_error(). How else can I do this? I am Python noob.

```
class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):      
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
        doTweet = all_data["id"]
        if username != our_own_id:
            #make sure you haven't already retweeted
            #make sure tweets aren't protected
            print(username) # just so we know it's working
            api.retweet(doTweet)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print('error')
        read_error = json.loads(status_code)
        print('Got an error with status code: ' + str(read_error))          
        return True # To continue listening

    def on_timeout(self):
        print('Timeout...')
        return True # To continue listening
```

---

```
try:
    if __name__ == '__main__':  
      listener = StdOutListener() 
      stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
      stream.filter(track=['#love'])

except KeyboardInterrupt:
   sys.exit()
```

Comment: I have tried to put api.retweet() in main without success.

Comment: I don't understand what the errors are. And please fix your indentation

Comment: @ValentinLorentz what should I change in the indentation? this is what I copy-pasted from IDLE.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz just re-copy-pasted and the try: line is now weirdly formatted. So that's a question: how to format?

Comment: Errors: added stream.filter(track=['#love']) (#love gets a lot of tweets). I am looking for a way to error check for this error message: tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'You have already retweeted this tweet.', 'code': 327}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your call to `api.retweet` in your `on_data` method as follows:

```
...
if username != our_own_id:
    print(username) # just so we know it's working
    try:
        api.retweet(doTweet)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        # add here a more complex error handling
        print(e)
```

Hope it helps.